# How to change pl/sql query into 2 "WHERE" clause

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have PL/SQL query have 2 different WHERE clause (`WHERE(1)`,`WHERE(2)`) for one Interactive Grid and I have a parameter if parameter have value is `1` then PL/SQL query will run with `WHERE(1)` else parameter have value is `2` then PL/SQL query run with `WHERE(2)`, hope someone can resolved my problem, thanks a lot.
This is my PL/SQL query:

```
if :P140101101_CHANGE = 1 then
select T.RDE_ID,
          T.RDE_SIP,
          T.V_IIT_CODE,
          T.V_IIT_NAME
from V_REQUISITION_DETAILS_V6 T
WHERE (T.REQ_ID = :P140101101_V_REQ_ID)

if :P140101101_CHANGE = 2 then
SELECT T.RDE_ID,
       T.RDE_SIP,
       T.V_IIT_CODE,
       T.V_IIT_NAME
  FROM V_REQUISITION_DETAILS_V6 T
 WHERE (T.REQ_ID = ::P140101101_V_REQ_ID) 
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM V_PRICE_LIST_LINES_PO32 PRI
         WHERE PRI.Iit_Id = T.Iit_Id)
   and (T.PLL_ID IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do this is to break it in 2 Interactive Grid region. And on each grid's Server-Side condition section select `Item = Value` type and apply condition `:P140101101_CHANGE = 1` or `2` accordingly

One other way is to use `Union` (I have not tested this one, but it should work)

```
select T.RDE_ID,
          T.RDE_SIP,
          T.V_IIT_CODE,
          T.V_IIT_NAME
from V_REQUISITION_DETAILS_V6 T
WHERE (T.REQ_ID = :P140101101_V_REQ_ID)
AND :P140101101_CHANGE = 1

UNION

SELECT T.RDE_ID,
       T.RDE_SIP,
       T.V_IIT_CODE,
       T.V_IIT_NAME
  FROM V_REQUISITION_DETAILS_V6 T
 WHERE (T.REQ_ID = ::P140101101_V_REQ_ID) 
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM V_PRICE_LIST_LINES_PO32 PRI
         WHERE PRI.Iit_Id = T.Iit_Id)
   AND (T.PLL_ID IS NULL)
   AND :P140101101_CHANGE = 2
```

Comment: Thank for your reply, I've find the way for my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OR` condition as follows:

```
SELECT T.RDE_ID,
       T.RDE_SIP,
       T.V_IIT_CODE,
       T.V_IIT_NAME
  FROM V_REQUISITION_DETAILS_V6 T
 WHERE (T.REQ_ID = :P140101101_V_REQ_ID) 
   AND ( :P140101101_V_REQ_ID <> 2 OR (EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM V_PRICE_LIST_LINES_PO32 PRI
         WHERE PRI.Iit_Id = T.Iit_Id)
   and (T.PLL_ID IS NULL)))
```

**Update**: for 4 conditions

```
SELECT T.RDE_ID,
       T.RDE_SIP,
       T.V_IIT_CODE,
       T.V_IIT_NAME
  FROM V_REQUISITION_DETAILS_V6 T
 WHERE (T.REQ_ID = :P140101101_V_REQ_ID) 
-- condition for 1 is irrelevant here  
-- AND ( :P140101101_SREACH_PRICE <> 1 OR (T.REQ_ID = :P140101101_V_REQ_ID))
   AND ( :P140101101_SREACH_PRICE <> 2 OR (EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                                    FROM V_PRICE_LIST_LINES_PO32 PRI
                                                     WHERE PRI.Iit_Id = T.Iit_Id)
                                                     and (T.PLL_ID IS NULL)))
   AND ( :P140101101_SREACH_PRICE <> 3 OR (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                                       FROM V_PRICE_LIST_LINES_PO32 PRI
                                                       WHERE PRI.Iit_Id = T.Iit_Id))) 
   AND ( :P140101101_SREACH_PRICE <> 4 OR (T.PLL_ID IS NOT NULL))
```

Comment: Thank for your reply, But when my pl/sql query have 4 condition i cant solved that conditon, could you have any idea for my problem

Comment: Then You must show those 4 conditions to us. then I will be able to help further. The answer was given considering the issue in your question

Comment: This is 4 conditions, please help me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62830179/12415421

Comment: Thank for your reply, I've find the way for my problem

Answer (score 0):

This is 4 conditions: @Tejash

```
SELECT T.RDE_ID,
       T.RDE_SIP,
       T.V_IIT_CODE,
       T.V_IIT_NAME
  FROM V_REQUISITION_DETAILS_V6 T
 WHERE (T.REQ_ID = :P140101101_V_REQ_ID) 
   AND ( :P140101101_SREACH_PRICE <> 1 OR (T.REQ_ID = :P140101101_V_REQ_ID))
   AND ( :P140101101_SREACH_PRICE <> 2 OR (EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                                    FROM V_PRICE_LIST_LINES_PO32 PRI
                                                     WHERE PRI.Iit_Id = T.Iit_Id)
                                                     and (T.PLL_ID IS NULL)))
   AND ( :P140101101_SREACH_PRICE <> 3 OR (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                                       FROM V_PRICE_LIST_LINES_PO32 PRI
                                                       WHERE PRI.Iit_Id = T.Iit_Id))) 
   AND ( :P140101101_SREACH_PRICE <> 4 OR (T.PLL_ID IS NOT NULL))
```